# How to use Coingecko Python wrapper with proxy?

Tags: python, proxy

A CoinGecko service has a Python wrapper that can be connected like this:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
price = cg.get_coin_by_id('tether')
```

I have a python code that parses а free proxy site and returns random proxy dict like {'https': '187.62.191.3:61256'}

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

def get_proxy():
    url = "https://www.ssl-site.com/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    return{'https': choice(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+':'+x[1], list(zip(map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]), map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}

get_proxy()



def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            print('Using proxy: {}'.format(proxy))
            r = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
            break
        except:
            pass
    return r
```

How to call CoinGecko API wrapper endpoints each time from new ip?

Comment: It looks like you might need to edit the API wrapper and patch it with your proxy example, or implement the coin desk API with proxies. I don't think you can wrap the wrapper with a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your proxies after initializing CoinGeckoAPI() using directly the session attribute and then call any API endpoints.
For example:

```py
import pycoingecko
cg=pycoingecko.CoinGeckoAPI()

# set up a proxy (or any other dictionary with proxies)
cg.session.proxies['https']='http://10.10.1.10:1080'

# you can check proxies by printing them
print(cg.session.proxies)
# output here should be: {'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080'}

# call an endpoint, for example get price of bitcoin in USD
cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')
```